# How to use groovy-maven-plugin with groovy 3.0.x?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, groovy-3.0

As per [groovy-maven-plugin](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/) documentation it is possible to specify a particular groovy version to be used in a maven build. This succeeds with *groovy-all* versions up to 2.4.9, but version 2.5.0 or higher will break the build with the followin message, when I call "mvn validate":

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.1.1:execute (default) on project groovy3demo: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.1.1:execute failed: Plugin org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:3.0.6 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

The reason is that there is no 'groovy-all-3.0.6.jar' [here in mavencentral repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/). Apparently the 'groovy-all-<version>.jar is no longer deployed since version 2.5.0-beta3, only sources and javadoc. Version 2.4.9 seems to be the latest version that succeeds.

So my question is: **How can I use groovy 3.x in my maven build?**

Thank you for any hint.

Here is my **pom.xml** and (besides a maven installation) you don't need more than that to reproduce the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.zaphodbeeblebrox</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy3demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version> <!-- 2.4.9 is the latest successful version -->
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>
                println '*** Generated Version Numbers and Timestamps ***'
                println '  [...]'
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the changes introduced with groovy v2.5 and described with [Release notes for Groovy 2.5](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html) and [GROOVY-8750](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8750), you should now use either the base groovy package or the wanted groovy modules, like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

To work with all groovy modules you can also use groovy-all dependency

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```